# Svelte TreeView not update when store data updates

Tags: svelte, svelte-component, svelte-store, svelte-4

I need to represent my data in a tree view and use as base the [TreeView](https://svelte.dev/repl/a3f724e24df54b9695402576ffd68fe3?version=4.2.0) from svelte.

What I figured out is that if the TreeView data changed, the html will not rerender the tree. The data object is updated but not the html.

I create a new sample based on the original: 
[Playground](https://svelte.dev/repl/1a38f292d73c4bc8a6f605e00c22cf53?version=4.2.0)

What I currently need to do is to clear the store and with a ms timeout set the new data:

```
const updateHacky = () => { 
    writableArray.set([])
    setTimeout(() => {
        writableArray.set([updateData])
    }, 1);
}
```

but what I expect is that on

```
writableArray.update(() => [updateData]);
```

the UI updates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with this code in `TreeView.svelte`:

```js
export let tree
const {label, children} = tree
```

The second line is only executed once - when the component is created. This means that when the component receives a new `tree` value, `label` and `children` don't get updated.

You can fix it by writing this instead:

```js
export let tree
$: ({ label, children } = tree)
```

Comment: @H.B. thanks for the edit, I didn't know about this syntax!

Comment: Thank you! Solved - thanks also for explanation